# Is Monster Kid's gender known?

Tags: undertale

I don't remember Monster Kid's gender being revealed in the game, although I don't seem to recall them being referred to as 'they' like Frisk or Chara. Is Monster Kid left as a 'they' just like them, or does Monster Kid have a gender canonically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wikia page for Monster Kid](https://undertale.fandom.com/wiki/Monster_Kid) he is referred to as male in the art book and uses the Japanese word for "himself" when playing the Japanese translation of the game.

Monster Kid does not seem to have any other references to their gender.